# Issues with jquery id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have this snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="menu-file-div">
  <label id="menu-file-label" for="id_menu_file">From File</label>
    <div class="input">
      <div id="file-upload">

        <input type="hidden" name="menu_file" id="id_menu_file" />

          <script type="text/javascript">var field_id = "id_menu_file";</script>
          <script type="text/javascript">var append_to_element_id = "menu-upload";</script>
          <script type="text/javascript">var loader_element_id = "newmenu-modal";</script>
        <noscript>
          <p>Please enable JavaScipt to upload a file.</p>
        </noscript>
      </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

In my console, when I try to use the jquery id selector, it fails to return the input element:

```
> $("#id_menu_file")
[]
```

Any thoughts on why this is so? I feel like I'm missing something simple. Thank you!

**EDIT** - some other javascript was removing the element, that is why it's not showing up. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Can't reproduce here: http://jsfiddle.net/UXGwK/

Comment: Is this HTML inside of a frame (iframe or regular)? That could make it difficult for jQuery to find your element, unless you give it the right context.

Comment: Maybe you're running your jQuery code before the `id_menu_file` is in the DOM? Try wrapping your function inside a `document.ready(function() {` or `$(function() {`.

Comment: As a side note, you do know that you only need one script tag for those three lines of code, not three, right?  If you like that style/formatting, more power to you, I just wanted to check in case you were new(-ish) to Javascript.

Comment: Fabricio, I thought of that, but OP wrote "In my console, when I try to use the jquery id selector"; unless his HTML file is HUGE, it's nearly impossible to run code in the console before "onReady" has happened.

Comment: I see, however, scripts run sequentially and I don't see where OP is calling his selector. =]

Comment: @machineghost yes it is indeed, it is automatically generated js that will be redone once I get some other stuff working.

Comment: How would I provide it with more context? Thanks for your help, I am relatively less experiences with js.

Comment: Ah; in that case (and since you said your code is not in a frame), onReady is almost certainly your problem.  You can use this code to test as much: $(function(){console.log($("#id_menu_file"))}); (you can run it from anywhere, first line, last line, wherever, and it should still work).

Comment: I've just test your html and I get this result:

$('#id_menu_file')

[<input type=​"hidden" name=​"menu_file" id=​"id_menu_file">​]

Probably you are missing something.

Comment: Ah; in that case (as Fabricio suggested in the comments) onReady is almost certainly your problem.  As for "How would I provide it with more context?", jQuery accepts an extra context argument, which limits the scope of the query (and thus speeds things up).  For instance, if you had a variable for a table called "$table", and you wanted to find TDs within it, you could do $("TD", $table).  When you have frames, it is often necessary to provide the frame as that second argument.

Comment: Doesn't matter how it runs in the console. Consoles are imperfect. Does the code work in your actual code? You haven't included the actual code in the question for some reason.

Comment: Also, are you including jQuery? The `$` sometimes has different meaning in the console if jQuery isn't loaded. Again, post your real code.

Comment: @amnotiam It does not run correctly in my browser and jquery is included. It works for other element ids in the console and browser.

Comment: @zallarak: Please update your question to show the actual code that isn't working.

Comment: @amnotiam When jquery is not loaded the selector call returns null, not []

Comment: Were you able to add my line of code?  If so, what did (or did not) get logged?

Comment: it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/srYWv/

Comment: @machineghost I tried your code and it did not work. Posted the reason why in an EDIT. It was my own fault, some other JS code was removing the element.

Comment: Glad you figured things out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat my first answer (which may be applicable to others reading this post later, and which was deleted despite the fact that it "fundamentally answer[ed] the question"):

```
Is this HTML inside of a frame (iframe or regular)? That could make it difficult for jQuery to find your element, unless you give it the right context.
```

To add a context to a jQuery selector you just provide that context as an extra argument, for example: $('TD', aFrameElement);

If the element in question is not inside a frame (which is the case for zallarak), the problem is almost certainly a timing issue: the jQuery selection is happening before the element has gotten loaded on the page.  You can test this theory by adding the following code (anywhere):

```
$(function(){
    console.log($("#id_menu_file"))
});
```

If that is the problem, simply wrap your code in `$(function(){` to fix matters.

Comment: Just for completeness for anyone reading later, there are three basic causes of an issue like this 1) element is in a frame, 2) jQuery selector is run before the element is loaded, 3) some other code is removing the element before the selector runs.  In this particular case, it was 3).

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$("#id_menu_file").get(0)
```

$(selector) return arrays

Comment: It should still display the elements of the array.